# How to cut numbers after 2 decimal spaces (JS)

Tags: javascript, html

How can I edit this code to where it shows only two slots to the right of decimal? (trying to make it look like currency).  Trying to set up a simple roommate calculator Below is the code that I have so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bill Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

<div id="centerDiv">

    <form name="formcalc">

        Bill Amount: <input type="text" name="bill1"><br>


        <div><h2>Jake pays:
        <div id="jake"></div></h2></div>

        <div><h2>Miguel pays:
        <div id="miguel"></div></h2></div>


        <input type="button" value="calculate" onClick="sumValues()">

    </form>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function sumValues()
        {
            var num1, jake, miguel;
            num1=Number(document.formcalc.bill1.value);

            jake=num1*0.6;
            miguel=num1*0.4;

            document.getElementById('jake').innerHTML = '$' +  jake;
            document.getElementById('miguel').innerHTML = '$' + miguel;
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `alert(parseFloat("1.23456") - (parseFloat("1.23456") % .01))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.toFixed(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

Also, don't use `.inerHTML` when the string you are working with doesn't contain any HTML and even if it did, don't use it unless you are in complete control of that string as [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) has security and performance implications. Use [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead.

Additionally, `type="text/javascript"` has not been needed on `script` elements for several years now.

Next, if you won't be submitting data anywhere, you don't need to wrap your fields in a `form` element or give your elements a `name`.

And, when you do need to get a reference to an element, get it through the [Document Object Model API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model), with (in my example) `.getElementById()`.

```html
        Bill Amount: <input id="bill"><br>

        <div><h2>Jake pays:
        <div id="jake"></div></h2></div>

        <div><h2>Miguel pays:
        <div id="miguel"></div></h2></div>

        <input type="button" value="calculate" onClick="sumValues()">
 

    <script>
        function sumValues() {
            var num1, jake, miguel;
            num1=Number(document.getElementById("bill").value);
            jake=num1*0.6;
            miguel=num1*0.4;
            document.getElementById('jake').textContent = '$' +  jake.toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById('miguel').textContent = '$' + miguel.toFixed(2);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: This is a clear duplicated question, no need to answer when this should be close voted.